# How to change navigation menu class to selected, when you have clicked on it?

Tags: jquery

It works fine, when I'm use --> ul li and a tag without span

See it on action: http://jsfiddle.net/diskzzokejs/VkKJF/3/

Bouth of examples works fine, but in span class="header_item_before" and span class="header_item_after" I have a images. How to keep images on change? And last tab bottom corner must be without image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("ul li:last").addClass(function() {
                 return "last_tab selected";
               });
```

to this:

```
$(".tab_header_item").removeClass("selected");
$(this).closest(".tab_header_item").addClass("selected");
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VkKJF/4/)

Comment: I did it with $("ul li:last").addClass(function() {
       return "last_tab selected";

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/VkKJF/6/

Comment: Bouth of examples works fine, but in span class="header_item_before" and span class="header_item_after" I have a images. How to keep images on change? And last tab bottom corner must be without image.